# Path does not exist in current context c# .net coding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.io.file

In my c# code when I used Path.GetExtension , It is showing "Path does not exist in current context". Seems libraries for Path does not exist in current application.
But I searched and found Path class defined in System.IO and System.IO is by default part of our application.
After included System.IO the error exist.

Comment: do you have `using System.IO;` on the beginning of your .cs file?

Comment: Yes you need to use namespace System.IO; then it will work

Comment: Please post the exact compiler error you get. Also, post the exact line of code (or lines of code) that give you that error.

Comment: The library for Path is the core .NET library, so it's *always* available. Obviously something is wrong with your code. Post your code, the *full* compile error and the line where it occured

Answer (score 13):

You need to add namespace

```html
using System.IO;
```

And your path should be :

```
string str= Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
```

Second way :

```
string str= System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
```

Then it will work.

Cheers !!